# Object detection with deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, object-recognition

I am getting familiar with video detection/tracking using neural networks. Specifically, I am referring to algorithms that take in input an image or a sequence of images and, for each frame, it returns a list of bounding boxes around each object that is present in the image. An example is given below

[image: An example of object detection output]

To do it with deep learning, one needs to train a neural network that takes in input an image and outputs a list of bounding boxes.

My problem is here: On every frame there will be a different number of bounding boxes, depending on how many objects are present on each image. However, the output of a neural network has a fixed number of neurons.

How do I fit a list of bounding boxes, which has a variable length, into the fix size output of a neural network? How is this problem normally solved?

Thank you upfront.